# Cordova: Get application uuid on ios

Tags: cordova

I have a question regarding phonegap / cordova:

**How do i get the application uuid?**

I could extract it from the string of: `cordova.file.applicationDirectory`
. But is there are more straightforward way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UUID like this:

```
var string = device.uuid;
```

Comment: Isn't this the UUID of the device? I am looking for the UUID of the application. Like in the location of the app's files: /var/mobile/Applications/<UUID>/...